# Facebook login page is empty and will not load

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, swift3

I implemented all of the macbook login steps from their website. And when I click my unbutton to present the Facebook login page, the Facebook safari login page will not load, or even attempt to load and is essentially blank. Here is my code. Can someone provide some edit or advice on what I should do to solve this problem. Here is my appdelagate. In my info.plist I've included the FacebookAppID, lsApplicationQuiersSchemes, Facebook display name. Ive also put my bundle identifier in on face books website. Is there anything I'm missing. When I press my Facebook button it presents a blank safari page.

```
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
     import ParseFacebookUtilsV4
import CoreData
 @UIApplicationMain
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,         UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
var window: UIWindow?
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

    PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebook(applicationLaunchOptions: launchOptions)
    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()

}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:. 
}
private func setupGlidingCollection() {
    var config = GlidingConfig.shared
    config.buttonsFont = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 22)
    config.inactiveButtonsColor = config.activeButtonColor
    GlidingConfig.shared = config
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Check your console, it should give an error.

Comment: it didn't. i don't know why